# ZyXel USG 40 portforwarding - does not work

Tags: router, port-forwarding

I am trying to forward ports from my router to my server, I am using the ZyXel USG 40 router.

When I access my server locally on my network it works. But, when I try to do it via my IP address it simply doesn't work (it doesn't respond).

Under Configuration -> NAT: I've added a new rule.

Incoming Interface: wan1 

Original IP: any

Mapped IP: My server local IP. 

Disabled the NAT Loopback.

Furthermore under Policy Control, I've added a new policy.

From: any
To: any (exl. ZyWall)
Source: any
Destination: NAT entity created in previous step
Service: any (intent to change that when it works to only desired ports)
User: any
Schedule: any

Action: allow

I don't understand why this is not working?

Answer (score 1):

The exactly "mode" depends on firmware version.
For newer one (4.62+) the "right" things to do are

Example: NAT the (WAN) 23000 port to internal 10.0.0.250:22
This is just an example for ONE port.
You can make a 1:1 NAT to get ALL ports

0. define the service (configuration=>object=>service)
   suppose ssh23k TCP, starting 23000, ending 23000
1. configuration=>network=>NAT
   virtual server, incoming wan, source IP any, external IP any,
   internal IP user defined, user defined internal IP 10.0.0.250,
   port mapping type port, protocol type tcp, external port 23000, internal port 22
   No enable NAT loopback
   (or port mapping type: service, external service ssh23k, internal SSH)
2. firewall: configuration=>security policy=>policies control
   name (whatever)
   from any
   to LAN1
   source (any or an object to limit to one IP)
   destination 10.0.0.250
   service ssh23k
   user any
   schedule none
   action allow
   log no

Answer (score 0):

You disabled NAT Loopback. This needs to be *enabled* in order to use your external IP address from within your network.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't help. Any other suggestions?